# How do you name a function in template.php to get picked up by theme() calls in page.tpl.php?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a Drupal 6 site with a simple theme I'm creating called NPT. In page.tpl I have this:

```
<?php print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'links primary-links')) ?>
```

That successfully calls this function in template.php:

```
npt_links()
```

However, I also have this in page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print theme('clinks', $secondary_links, array('class' => 'secondary-links')) ?>
```

And that *does not* call this function in template.php:

```
npt_clinks()
```

But it should, as I'm calling the "clinks" hook parameter in the theme() call.

Any ideas why this hook isn't being called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you declared the `clinks` theme function in the [theme registry](http://drupal.org/node/132442#theme-registry)?

Comment: +1 - As the naming is correct and 'clinks' sounds like a custom addition, this is the most likely cause.

Comment: Can you clarify? From that link: "PHPTemplate engine takes care of registering on behalf of the theme so in most situations you will not have to register manually."

Comment: PHPTemplate registers all the default ones, like `links`, `list_item`, etc. You've made a custom one, `clinks`, and as such PHPTemplate and Drupal have no idea it exists.